# Bounding the norm of an inverse matrix from above

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

In my situation I have an $s\times k$ integer matrix $X$ of rank $s$ and an $k\times k$ positive diagonal matrix $D$, where $s\leq k$. Say I can bound $||X||_{\infty}$, and I know $D$ precisely. Can I bound the norm of $(XDX^{t})^{-1}$ from above? I tried looking at the determinant, which has a nice expression:

$det(XDX^{t})=\sum_{\sigma}d_{\sigma}\cdot m^{2}_{\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is a choice of $s$ elements from $1,...,k$, $d_{\sigma}$ is the product of the appropriate elements of $D$ and $m_{\sigma}$ is the appropriate minor of $X$. This shows the determinant is not too small (?).

If anyone has any idea or any scheme to bound the inverses of such matrices, I would be very intersted and thankful!

Also, in my particular case $X=(Id_{s},X_0)$ the elements of $D$ are between greater than $1$,and $d_{1}>d_{2}>\dots>d_{k}$, if that helps.

Comment: Could you precisely define the norm ? Is it the maximum of absolute values of the entries of matrix or the operator norm between  finite dimensional $\ell^\infty$ spaces ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc For me you can assume $X$ is bounded in any norm most convenient for the question - in practice I have very good control on $X$.

Comment: How do you know that $XDX^t$ is invertible ? Are there any additional assumptions on $X$ besides the entries are integer numbers ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I mean that $D$ is invertible and $X$ has rank $s$, I will edit, thank you.

Comment: If you know only $D$ as well as the rank and the norm of $X$, the answer is negative in general, because $X$ (and hence $XDX^T$) can be arbitrarily close to a singular matrix.

Comment: @Espace' etale If $X=[I_s X_0]$ and $D$ is diagonal then the norm of the inverse can be bounded by the inverse of the minimum of the diagonal entries of $D,$ if I am not mistaken.  I can show it for $k=3$ and $s=2.$ Perhaps it can be generalized further. Shall I type the answer in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make use of the euclidean norm for vectors and the operator norm for matrices.

Let $$X=\begin{bmatrix} I_s & X_0
\end{bmatrix} \quad  D= \begin{bmatrix} D_s & 0 \\
0 & D_r
\end{bmatrix},$$ where $D_s$ denotes the $s\times s$ block of the matrix $D.$
Then
$$XDX^t= D_s+X_0D_rX_0^t\ge D_s$$
Hence by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$\|XDX^tv\|\,\|v\|\ge \langle XDX^t v,v\rangle \ge \langle D_sv,v\rangle\ge \min_{1\le j\le s} d_j\, \|v\|^2$$
Therefore for $d:=\displaystyle \min_{1\le j\le s}d_j$ we have $$\|XDX^tv\|\ge d\, \|v\|$$
The operator $XDX^t$ is invertible and $\|(XDX^t)^{-1}\|\le d^{-1}.$

**Remark** The entries $d_{s+1},d_{s+2},\ldots, d_k$ are not involved in the estimate.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great argument! In addition it doesn't use any bounds on the norm of $X$. Can you see if one can also bound $||(XDX^{t})^{-1}D_{s}||$ from above?  It seems from your argument that it could be possible...

Comment: I am able to show that $\|D_s^{1/2}(XDX^t)^{-1}D_s^{1/2}\|\le 1$ . Concerning $(XDX^t)^{-1}D_s$ it implies that its eigenvalues have absolute value less or equal to $1.$ Shall I extend the answer by that ?

Comment: Thank you! You’ve helped me a ton.

Comment: I notice now a problem with your last comment. You have indeed shown that $(XDX^{t})^{-1}D_{s}$ has eignvalues of absolute values greater than 1, but this matrix is not symmetric, so it doesn’t help us bound the norm! I am able to obtain some bounds but really bad ones. Could you perhaps share your thoughts on how to bound the norm of $(XDX^{t})^{-1}D_{s} $?